# Dependency injection in authentication options

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to inject a service into a `ValidationHandler` that inherits from `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` which validates the Jwt's signature. Unfortunately, to use the handler, I have to use object initialization with `new` in ConfigureServices, which means I can't use the injected services that comes with adding the service to the dependency container.

```
    public class DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler : JwtSecurityTokenHandler
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

        public DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler(IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _cache = cache;
        }
    }
```

```
services.AddTransient<DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler>();
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer(opts => 
      {
          opts.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
          opts.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler(???));
      });
```

So what can I do to still be able to use the `IMemoryCache`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an implementation of `IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>`:

```
public class JwtOptionsConfigurer : IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    private readonly DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler _tokenValidator;

    public JwtOptionsConfigurer(DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler tokenValidator)
    {
        _tokenValidator = tokenValidator;
    }

    public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(_tokenValidator);
    }

    public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        Configure(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options);
    }
}
```

And then add it like so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, JwtOptionsConfigurer>();
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer();
```

We still need to call `.AddJwtBearer()` because that does some necessary registrations, etc.

Side note (in case it's useful to anyone): the authentication middleware creates a new `JwtBearerOptions` every time it is needed, so the configuration code above will be run multiple times.